# Key Reinstalation Attack WPA2 No Funciona

Tags: python, linux

`OS kali-linux-2018.1-amd64.iso`

[archive /etc/network/interfaces]

> 

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.11
network 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

> 

```
DNSMASQ config:

no-resolv
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.0.10,192.168.0.200,8h
dhcp-option=3,192.168.0.1
dhcp-option=6,192.168.0.1
server=1.1.1.1
server=1.0.0.1
log-queries
log-dhcp
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Interfaces that are used
INTERNET=$1
REPEATER=$2

#Configuring IP address of malicious AP
ip addr del 192.168.0.1/24 dev $REPEATER 2> /dev/null || true
ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev $REPEATER

#Enabling IP forwaring
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 > /dev/null

#Enabling NAT
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INTERNET -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $REPEATER -o $INTERNET -j ACCEPT

#Starting DHCP and DNS service
dnsmasq -d -C dnsmasq.conf &> dnsmasq.log
```

no condigo dar ip a un dispositivo android,me dice que intenta obtener la direcion ip pero nunca laobtiene esperas 15 segunds y se desconecta del ap falso,podria ser un problema con Selinux ocon los puertos en red local?

sudo ./krack_all_zero_tk.py wlan1 wlan0 usb0 alberto -t MAC_ADDRESS

apt-get install python-pip
pip install pycryptodome

[image: KrackAttack script]

Comment: Por la decoración de ventanas imagino que estás usando máquinas virtuales. ¿Le estás pasando el dispositivo WiFi a la máquina virtual de manera directa a través de USB o estás usando la interfaz del anfitrión? En caso de que lo estés haciendo bien, ¿podrías compartir la configuración de `dnsmasq` para ver si están bien los rangos IPs?

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta (pulsa en este enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/269720/edit) para agregar esa información a tu pregunta en vez de ponerla como comentario. No se lee igual y puede llevar a confusión. También sería bueno que indicaras la salida de `ip addr list` antes de que ejecutes `dnsmasq` para saber si existe alguna interfaz con la dirección IP adecuada para dar servicio.

Answer (score 1):

El problema por el que `dnsmasq` no está funcionando correctamente en tu máquina virtual es porque no tiene ninguna dirección IP asignada en la interfaz `wlan0` sobre la que ofrecer el servicio DHCP configurado (IPs dentro del rango `192.168.0.10` a `192.168.0.200`).

Para agregar una IP en `wlan0` dentro de esa red (pero fuera de ese rango) necesitas ejecutar la siguiente instrucción (suponiendo que le quieres dar, por ejemplo, la IP `192.168.100.1`):

```
ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev wlan0
```

Tras eso deberías reiniciar el servidor `dnsmasq` para que comience a funcionar con normalidad.

Comment: cuando reinicio dnsmasq poniendo el comando service dnmasq stop no funciona. como lo tengo que hacer?

Comment: Es probable que si tienes el archivo de configuración en el directorio de trabajo debas usar (como se deja entrever en alguna captura de pantalla) `dnsmasq -d -C dnsmasq.conf` en vez de hacer uso del servicio (que aloja el archivo de configuración en `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` u otra ruta dentro de `/etc` por norma general).

Comment: como puedo reiniciar dnsmasq reinicio el network-manager?

Comment: No sé qué distribución de Linux estarás usando, pero si quieres asegurarte de que no existe una instancia previa en ejecución cuando vayas a ejecutar tu instancia haz un `killall dnsmasq; sleep 2; killall -9 dnsmasq`. Eso finalizará la ejecución "suavemente" de la instancia anterior y tras dos segundos forzará la finalizará inmediata en caso de que la primera vez no lo hiciera.

Comment: lo he echo y dice dos veces proces not found y ejecuto el script para ver si funciona y nada todo esto poniendo el comando ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev wlan0 uso kali linux de distribución

Comment: Si usas kali deberías tener portapapeles bidireccional para poder copiar/pegar lo que te sale en el terminal en vez de hacer capturas de pantalla. Lo de que no hay procesos simplemente significa que no estaba el servicio arrancado. Cuando arranques el script haz `LANG=C netstat -apn | grep LISTEN` para comprobar si está escuchando peticiones correctamente.

Comment: esta funcionando bien ?

Comment: puede ser que tengo que abrir el puerto ?

Comment: No, está funcionando sólo como servidor DNS. ¿Tu archivo `dnsmasq.conf` qué contiene? ¿Puedes compartir su contenido exacto? Ahora tienes todo seguido y no sé si es porque lo has abierto con el bloc de notas o cuál podría ser el motivo por el que lo compartirse con todo seguido. Necesito el contenido literal, exacto. También dime la versión de Kali Linux usas para bajarme la misma para las pruebas.

Comment: la version es la 2018.4 y la configuracion de dnsmasq.conf te la he puesto arriba